# Git Pushing from a local branch to a remote tracking branch

Tags: git, branch, branching-and-merging

I have a master branch and branched out from it to a build branch.

I cloned this repository to a different machine.
I created a branch my_build to track the remote build branch.
Now i have few commits made in my_build branch.
I want to push these changes to Remote build branch.

I tried pulling from my Remote build branch and it worked.

### But is there a way that i can push my commits in my_build branch to Remotes build branch?

I have a master and two branches Branch A and Branch B branched from master at the same point.

I am in Branch A and i want to push my commits to Branch B How can i do this?

---

I have a master and a branch A.

Cloned this to another machine.

Created another branch B made some commits in B. B is not tracking A. Now how can i push my changes from B to A.

How can i pull A's Changes to my branch B.

And i all the above cases my master and all repos are non-bare Repos.

Answer (score 1):

have a look at the refspec format of [git pull](http://kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-push.html)

```
git push origin branch_from:branch_to
```